# Hibernate EntityExistsException on retrieval

Tags: hibernate

I got a puzzling EntityExistsException in the following query -

```
TypedQuery<T> typedQuery = em.createQuery(query);
return result = typedQuery.getSingleResult(); // <-- exception thrown here
```

I thought this exception should normally occur when persisting, not when retrieving. Can you please shed some clues under which circumstances EntityExistsException can occur during a retrieval operation? Thanks.

> javax.persistence.EntityExistsException: A different object with the
>   same identifier value was already associated with the session :
>   [...@d8e152db]    at
>   org.hibernate.jpa.spi.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.convert(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1735)
>   ~[hibernate-entitymanager-4.3.0.Final.jar:4.3.0.Final]    at
>   org.hibernate.jpa.spi.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.convert(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1677)
>   ~[hibernate-entitymanager-4.3.0.Final.jar:4.3.0.Final]    at
>   org.hibernate.jpa.internal.QueryImpl.getSingleResult(QueryImpl.java:524)
>   ~[hibernate-entitymanager-4.3.0.Final.jar:4.3.0.Final]    at
>   org.hibernate.jpa.criteria.compile.CriteriaQueryTypeQueryAdapter.getSingleResult(CriteriaQueryTypeQueryAdapter.java:71)
>   ~[hibernate-entitymanager-4.3.0.Final.jar:4.3.0.Final] ... ...

Comment: may be this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13762713/a-different-object-with-the-same-identifier-value-was-already-associated-with-th

Answer (score 1):

Your `em` might have an object already loaded in it, when you do `typedQuery.getSingleResult()` you are reloading the existing object that is in hibernate cache(causes the above exception). So before running the typed query flush and clear see if it works

```
em.flush();
em.clear();

//and your typed query goes here
```

Or if you know the exact object that is causing then you can do

`session.evict(theExactObject)`

Comment: Why doesn't hibernate then return the existing object in the cache? Or is there a way to do so? I am implementating a web-app, and by nature when user submits a form, I have lost reference to the entity (only have string value of ID). So, I am trying to re-query the entity object.

Comment: You shouldn't requery, instead use `refresh()` method, so entity manage should bring the latest object changes from db for the object.